# Is it possible to have a car in a steampunk world?

Tags: internal-consistency, technology

Is it possible to build a car or car like vehicle that is steam powered?

Comment: You mean like the [ones we built](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steam_car) a hundred years ago?

Comment: Those weren't steam powered. We didn't build cars until we had a simple combustion engine.

Comment: @BryanMcClure Wikipedia says they were developed at the same time, yes. But I don't see any reason why ICE technology is *required* for steam cars. It's easy to imagine the possibility of the ICE not being invented, or being invented much later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cars have been imagined for a very long time, and people have been trying to build them ever since the technology to do so has been around.

Leonardo da Vinci built a "car" powered by springs for his patron in the late 1400's. Unfortunatly, modern reproductions show that it could only have moved under its own power for a few tens of metres before the springs unwound.

[image: Leonardo's car]

The first steam powered "car" was developed in France by Nicolas-Joseph Cugnot in 1769. He also had the first car accident, the same year. Looking at the engine, it would have been very inefficient unlike the later Watt engines), burned through a huge amount of fuel very quickly and had a low power to weight ratio. Thundering down the road at walking speed just doesn't have the right ring to it.

[image: Nicolas-Joseph Cugnot in 1769]

Steam and even electric cars finally came into prominence in the last part of the 1800's. Engines were more developed, more fuel efficient and had higher power to weight ratios. Steam cars continued in production right up until the 1920's (and have been proposed from time to time as replacements for modern cars), but internal combustion engines have much higher power to weight ratios, can be more compact (no external boilers or condensers) and are more convenient (no extra fluids, no worrying about freezing the boiler water, smaller radiators if you have a condenser, etc.)

So steam cars are quite possible (and if you really want to bend things out of shape, Hero of Alexandria created simple stream and atmospheric engines as far back as the first century AD....)

Answer (score 6):

The [Stanley Steamer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanley_Motor_Carriage_Company) set a speed record of 127 mph over a one mile course in 1906. If the internal combustion engine had not improved dramatically during the early 1900s, there is no reason to believe that steam-powered automobiles would not have become widespread. Of course, steamers tend to be more expensive than IC engines for powers of less than 100 horsepower or so, so the automobile revolution would not have been as pervasive as it was.

Even so, a steampunk automobile seems perfectly feasible.